# Google Weave (libiota) Host Hvac

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-weave

I followed [these steps](https://developers.google.com/weave/guides/device-dev/getting-started) to get the *Host Light* example device registered on Weave and running on a Raspberry Pi 3. I'm able to control it with Home and the Weave Console.

Now I'm trying to do the same for a *Host Hvac* device (I looked at the [Hvac example for the MW302](https://weave.googlesource.com/weave/libiota/+/HEAD/examples/mw302/hvac/main.c) as a reference), but I'm not able to register the device with **./out/host/examples/hvac/hvac -r xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx**.

It gets stuck at the following, with no visible errors:

```
[(4068588.179)I daemon.c:146] Heap state at daemon_connected: free=0, iota_allocated=15721, iota_max_allocated=15754
[(4068588.180)I daemon.c:152] Daemon connected.
```

With the *Host Light* example, I do see the device registering and it works fine:

```
[(4069131.290)I daemon.c:268] Waiting for registration message to be sent.
[(4069131.290)I daemon.c:146] Heap state at daemon_connected: free=0, iota_allocated=15234, iota_max_allocated=15268
[(4069131.290)I daemon.c:152] Daemon connected.
[(4069131.290)I daemon.c:137] Registering with ticket xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
[(4069131.290)I weave_http.c:98] Sending PATCH Request https://www.googleapis.com/weave/v1/registrationTickets/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[(4069133.198)I weave_register.c:205] Sending Registration Finalize Request
[(4069133.198)I weave_http.c:98] Sending POST Request https://www.googleapis.com/weave/v1/registrationTickets/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/finalize?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[(4069135.880)I settings.c:71] Device id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
[(4069135.880)I weave_register.c:233] Sending Registration OAuth Request
[(4069135.880)I weave_http.c:98] Sending POST Request https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
[(4069135.196)I weave_register.c:270] Registration Complete
[(4069135.196)I dev_framework.c:295] Heap state at daemon_registered: free=0, iota_allocated=23704, iota_max_allocated=35344
[(4069135.196)I dev_framework.c:296] Registration Succeeded.

> [(4069135.197)I weave.c:550] Fetching Command Queue
```

Has anyone managed to create a *Host Hvac* device successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's now an Hvac host example in the Libiota repo: https://weave.googlesource.com/weave/libiota/+/master/examples/host/hvac_controller/

For those of you working on running any of the host example devices on a Raspberry Pi, note that you might need the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libldap2-dev libidn11-dev libssh2-1-dev libkrb5-dev librtmp-dev
```

Also weave_client (used to register the device) needs Pycurl on your Linux machine. Download the source from [pycurl.io](http://pycurl.io) and install it with `python setup.py install`. You may need to install these dependencies as well:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

> not able to register the device with ./out/host/examples/hvac/hvac -r xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.
>
> It gets stuck at the following, with no visible errors:

I think that you add the argc, argv in the main() and HostIotaFrameworkConfig config

Eg:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)

HostIotaFrameworkConfig config = (HostIotaFrameworkConfig) {

  .base =
      (IotaFrameworkConfig){
          .cli_commands = NULL,
          .num_commands = 0,
          .builder = create_daemon_,
      },
  .argc = argc,
  .argv = argv,
  .user_data = NULL,

};
```